# Vue is not update DOM when object property changes in array of objects

Tags: vue.js, object, vuejs2, vuejs3, arrayobject

I have a const array of objects which set to the data property on created(), I am trying to update the object properties as the user entered the form, the Console print shows the value updated, but the DOM is changing. DOM is updated when the key value is changed too but I do not want to change the key value

Data Array:

```
const invoices = [
  {
    number: "BBRFL",
    client: "Ellison Daugherty",
    amount: 8800,
    status: "Paid",
  },
  {
    number: "TYUBK",
    client: "Myrna Vinson",
    amount: 4097,
    status: "Paid",
  },
  {
    number: "IRUBR",
    client: "Mcmillan Warner",
    amount: 6466,
    status: "Draft",
  },
];
```

Here is the app.

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    "create-invoice": CreateInvoice,
    "invoice-item": InvoiceItem,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      invoices: invoices,
      status: null,
    };
  },
  created: function () {
    const invoices = localStorage.getItem("invoices");
    if (invoices) {
      this.invoices = JSON.parse(invoices);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    count: function () {
      return this.filteredInvoices.length;
    },
    filteredInvoices: function () {
      if (this.status) {
        return this.invoices.filter((invoice) => invoice.status == this.status);
      }
      return this.invoices;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    saveInvoice(invoice) {
      this.invoices.push(invoice);
    },
    invoiceUpdate(invoice) {
      const index = this.invoices.findIndex((i) => i.number === invoice.number);

      // this.invoices.splice(index, 1, invoice);
      
      Vue.set(this.invoices[index], "client", invoice.client);
      Vue.set(this.invoices[index], "amount", invoice.amount);
      Vue.set(this.invoices[index], "status", invoice.status);
    },
    invoiceDelete(number) {
      const index = this.invoices.findIndex((i) => i.number === number);
      this.invoices.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },

  watch: {
    invoices: {
      deep: true,
      handler: function (invoices) {
        localStorage.setItem("invoices", JSON.stringify(invoices));
      },
    },
  },
  template: `
  <div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
            <h1>Invoices</h1>
            <p class="text-dark">There are {{count}} Total Invoices</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-start" style="margin-top: 10px">
          <label for="status">Filter</label>
            <select name="filter" id="status" class="form-control" v-model="status">
              <option value="Draft">Draft</option>
              <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
              <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-right" style="margin-top: 10px">
            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4" id="createInvoice">
              New Invoice
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row mt-2 mb-2">
            <div
              class="invoice col-md-12"
            >
              <invoice-item
                v-for="(n, index) in filteredInvoices"
                :key="n.number"
                :initial-client="n.client"
                :initial-number="n.number"
                :initial-amount="n.amount"
                :initial-status="n.status"
                @update-invoice="invoiceUpdate"
                @delete-invoice="invoiceDelete"
              ></invoice-item>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center" v-if="filteredInvoices.length === 0"><p>No invoice found</p></div>
           
          </div>
        </div>
        <create-invoice @saveInvoice="saveInvoice" ></create-invoice>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
});
```

I had tried, this.$set, Vue.set, Direct assigning to property, assingment using splice function, but none of working. It only works with the change of value of key in for loop. Which I do not want to update.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/royallife88/4nbLr651/#&togetherjs=Q2U9U4biFU)

Any Help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is confusing, do you want the DOM to get updated or not?

Comment: This is specific to InvoiceItem implementation, which is omitted. That you need to change key suggests that the component is not reactive and needs to be remounted in order to render updated props

Comment: DOM is not changing as the object data changes in invoiceUpdate method.

Comment: `this.invoices.splice()` is the proper syntax here - not `Vue.set()` You may need to add a watcher in `InvoiceItem` to catch changes to `initial-amount`, `initial-client` and so on.

Comment: there already a watcher in code, If there need to make for watcher let me know